# How to add AnimatedTabControl in MahApps.Metro?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, mahapps.metro

I have started learning `MahApps.Metro`. I read the documentation and got a problem. How to add `AnimatedTabControl`?

I've included `ResourceDictionaries`:

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Purple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/FlatButton.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

After that I started to develop the window:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:behaviours="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Behaviours;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="MyProject" ShowIconOnTitleBar="True" SaveWindowPosition="True" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\MetroStyles.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Controls:MetroWindow.WindowCommands>
        <Controls:WindowCommands>
            <Button Content="about" />
            <Button Content="settings" />
        </Controls:WindowCommands>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.WindowCommands>

    <Grid>
        <Controls:TransitioningContentControl x:Name="Transitioning" Transition="RightReplaceTransition">

        </Controls:TransitioningContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

`Metro` window works fine but I have no idea how to add `AnimatedTabControl`... It's not included in `Controls:` namespace.

I want to do something like that:
[image: Tabs]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You add the

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
```

to the

```
 <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

element at the top of the .xaml then your TabControl will be animated (you still use the `TabControl` tag but it will use the Controls.AnimatedTabControl style..

Here's the example of the whole ResourceDictionary tag

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Ahhh, so I need to create a new tab control: `<TabControl><TabItem Content="Item1" /><TabItem Content="Item2" /></TabControl>`? I'll check it out this evening, because now I'm in the work:)

Comment: Yes your tab control will automatically will be animated as long as you add the resource to the animatedtabcontrol